# Linux - sorting while preserving header

Tags: sort

There have been a number of questions posed about how to sort data while preserving the header at the top.  The answers I've seen don't seem to be all that general - they're not flexible enough to support both file-based and stream-based sorting, and they don't allow for sort options.

How, oh how, would you generalize this?

Answer (score 1):

This sorts whatever is provided as stdin:

```
perl -e 'print scalar <>, sort <>;'
```

Example:

```
# echo -e "Heading\n2\n1"|perl -e 'print scalar <>, sort <>;'
Heading
1
2
```

If you want to sort a file just pipe it in:

```
echo -e "Heading\n2\n1" >/tmp/test
</tmp/test perl -e 'print scalar <>, sort <>;'
```

The only thing to be wary of is trying to sort a file in-place.

Comment: That is nice, but not so great if you want to sort any way other than lexicographically, record by record.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little script that does the trick:

```
#!/bin/bash

ARGS=()

while (( $# > 0 )) ; do
    [[ -f "$1" ]] && break
    ARGS+=( "$1" )
    shift
done

awk -v SORT_ARGS="${ARGS[*]}" '
    ( NR == 1 ) {
        print
        next
    }
    {
        print | "sort " SORT_ARGS
    }
' $@
```

A little greasiness in the case where a sort arg might actually be a file; this logic could probably be tightened up.  Works nicely for me in general though..